# Can I write Jetpack Compose components in Java?

Tags: java, android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible to write Jetpack Compose components in Java? All of the documentation seems to only give examples in Kotlin.  If not, is there any future plan to allow components to be implemented in Java?

Comment: Rumor has it that when someone learns Kotlin, they will not look back to write code in Java again (unless they have to)...

Answer (score 83, accepted):

No, you can't write Jetpack Compose components in Java, and there are no future plans to allow this (source: I work on Compose).   Note that this is not the same thing as using components created in Compose from a Java app, which [is possible](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop).

Jetpack Compose makes heavy use of Kotlin features such as coroutines, and `@Composable` methods require transformations that are done by a Kotlin compiler plugin.  There is no way to get access to these from Java.

Comment: So can i safely assume that we are done with java in android?

Comment: @Roker if you want to write components in Compose, yes.  For the rest of the Android platform, while [we do recommend Kotlin](https://developer.android.com/kotlin) and think it has a lot of benefits, Java is still a fully supported language.

Comment: very interesting, nice to "know" someone who works on it, that's pretty cool :)

Comment: @Ryan so for an android developer to get the full advantages of new features in the future he should start using kotlin instead of java ?

Comment: @RyanM if I have a java activity can I use a compose component?  IE hard to find an example of calling setContent(...) from a java class in any examples

Comment: Very unfortunate of Google to do this, starting a slow but sure dumping and neglect of the very language that has brought android and it's entire ecosystem to where it is. Might simply be some petty reason like their just concluded lawsuit with Oracle! But now that this is behind them, it may be time for them to rethink what they are doing. @RyanM

Comment: So this is Google's way of phasing out Java? SMH.

Comment: @RyanM How is Java a fully supported language if building things with the UI Toolkit isn't fully supported in Java. I think it's fine to say that Java is a fully supported language for PR purposes but this is stack overflow, just tell us straight up that Google is phasing out Java.

Comment: @DonKariro Do you really expect them to support 2 languages forever? Compose needs many features of the Kotlin language.

Comment: @DonKariro you said it perfectly. And the saddest part is Google still doesnt realise- THAT is the single largest reason developers jumped to Flutter! And come 2023 it'll be a sham to ignore the Java JDKs superiority in Features & Performance. If Dart has a way better version than compose. way way better & logical. And if Flutter/Dart did it from scratch... Im sure Google could have done an Alt version with Java.

Comment: @RyanM: So is it possible to do the reverse Kotlin which supports java code?

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure what you mean by that exactly, but in general:  Kotlin has excellent interoperability with Java; you can [call most Kotlin code from Java](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-to-kotlin-interop.html), as well as [call Java code from Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html).

Comment: @lostintranslation One way would be to create a wrapper Kotlin fragment and make use of it in your Java Fragment/Activity. You can check this sample commit I created: https://github.com/vighnesh153/android-tuts/commit/0ea7cfec3c9040d67bbc63f01062bbd5da2f4c43