# Call Jetpack Compose element from a java file

Tags: java, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use Jetpack Compose UI element in the existed XML from the activity, using `databinding` and `setContent()`.
This is the xml element:

```
    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
            android:id="@+id/save_btn_compose"                 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
```

I'm use this syntax in kotlin activity file and it works smoothly:

```
binding.ComposeView.setContent{
    MainActionButtonKt.MainActionButton(true, R.string.complete_job, R.drawable.ic_complete_btn_icon, false);
}
```

([got it from android's duc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis))

**What is the equivalent for java activity file?** I I tried to do that:

```
binding.saveBtnCompose.setContent((composer, integer) -> {
     MainActionButton(true, R.string.complete_job, R.drawable.ic_complete_btn_icon, false);
     return null;
});
```

but I got a compile error:

```
required: boolean, int, Integer, boolean, Composer, int, int
found:    boolean, int, int,     boolean

reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks !

Comment: Compose is kotlin only, I guess you can't use anything `@Composable` annotated from java.

Comment: You can't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433437/can-i-write-jetpack-compose-components-in-java

Answer (score 5):

You can use.

Create a kotlin function at anywhere else

```
fun setContent(composeView:ComposeView, composeparam1: Boolean){
    composeView.setContent {
        CallYourComposeFunction(composeparam1)
    }
}
```

Then call this from your java code by giving composeView from xml.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the above answer, if you want to use the equivalent to `setContent` without the need for first setting an xml layout, you can write a glue function like this:

```
fun setContentToMyScreen(activity: ComponentActivity, myParam: Boolean) {
    activity.setContent {
        MyScreen(myParam)
    }
}

@Composable
fun MyScreen(myParam: Boolean) {
    ...
}
```

That can then be called from a java Activity like so in `onCreate`:

```
setContentToMyScreen(this, true);
```