# java language options not show in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[i want to create a new project but after select api level there no options for select java and project default open in kotlin. What can i do?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0p4U.jpg)

i want to create a new project but after select api level there no options for select java and project default open in kotlin. What can i do?

Comment: Compose projects do not support Java. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433437/can-i-write-jetpack-compose-components-in-java

Comment: You selected Jetpack compose activity.  Go to previous and select ```Empty Activity``` not `Empty Compose Activity`

Answer (score 18):

Don't Click on empty Activity ... Select the Empty Views activity... Its done bcoz of android new version i.e. Flamingo.

Comment: Could you edit to explain why Empty Activity only allows for Kotlin while Empty Views Activity allows for both?

Answer (score 4):

I could be mistaken but when you start a new project you might be choosing templates that support only Kotlin as a language.

Try to choose basic activity, bottom navigation or similar templates that allow you to choose either Java or Kotlin as a language.

Hope this helps or let me know where exactly in the start phase you are facing this issue.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Don't Create a Empty Activity rather create a Empty Views Activity in the Layout Section

Answer (score 1):

This is due to new version flamigo select empty views activity from it java language will be visible :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are going to create the first `Activity` in your project, then just select `No Activity` and you can choose a language, Java or Kotlin.
[First, select No Activity and then next, finally, you can choose a language][image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Click in the start on Empty Views Activity and then you can choise Java :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably choose compose template this  works on Kotlin only not supported by Java.

This problem occurs when I am selecting the empty activity while creating my application, you have to select empty views activity then the java select option is available. or in no  activity also java selector is available