# Not showing language option after selecting project template in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The "New Project" wizard in Android Studio is not showing the "Language" option. I want to use Java, but it's forcing me to use Kotlin.

[image: Language option is missing.]

I am expecting to use Java for Android development.  How can I make a Java project?

Answer (score 21):

You've selected a [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) project template, and [Jetpack Compose can only be used with Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66433621/208273).

Specifically, you've selected the "Empty Activity" template shown below that has the Jetpack Compose logo on it:

[image: "New Project" wizard with "Empty Activity" selected. The image above "Empty Activity" displays the Jetpack Compose logo.]

To solve this, select any template with "Views" in the name, or select the "No Activity" template.  You'll be given the "Language" dropdown in any of those templates and will be able to select Java there:

[image: New project wizard showing the configuration for an "Empty Views Activity" project. A "Language" dropdown with "Java" and "Kotlin" options is present.]

That said, [Android development is becoming increasingly Kotlin-first](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/first); you may wish to consider trying Kotlin.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using `Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 1`

Except for the selected activity, you can select and use the Java language for other Activities.

This Selected Activity is Jetpack Compose Activity. Jetpack Compose supports only Kotlin language.

For more details: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose

[image]