# Change language in android studio from kotlin to java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio

i selected kotlin by mistake at the time of installation of android studio now how to change it to java?

I haven't started to code yet so no worries about files or anything

And i have started the project so provide the solution to change the language after starting the project

And i also tried clean installation but whenever i reinstall it doesn't even give me option to select a language, however it gave me option to create a new project and everything...

When i create a new project i don't get option to select a language or i counld have made  a new project

And also a default file named MainActivity.kt should be in .java

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about this. With each new project creation, Android Studio lets you choose the language in which the project will be.

[image]

Comment: I am not getting that option to select the language at the creation of a project

Comment: @Keval
what version of android studio do you have installed?

Comment: @lvan Abakumov Flamingo 2022.2.1 Patch 2

Comment: @Keval
Have you looked at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76065186/8644685)?

It says here that if you choose a project with jetpack compose, then in this case there will be only Kotlin.