How can I change the language from Kotlin to Java?

There is no option for Java language. How can I change it from Kotlin to Java?
I tried to change the language but there is no option for it. Please suggest me a solution to get rid of this problem. I checked this option tools>kotlin>decompile to java, but it is disabled.

This question is similar to: Not showing language option after selecting project template in Android Studio. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66433437/can-i-write-jetpack-compose-components-in-java

That property has nothing to do with whether your project is Kotlin or Java, it only governs which language the Gradle build-file(s) uses (Groovy or Kotlin).

This is not the programming language but the build configuration language for the Gradle build.

Remove each line of code containing 'org.jetbrains.kotlin' that you find in the Gradle file
I hope this will help you.

Your answers are basically comments (in my opinion).
